Big layout Android/Java
I want to make a minesweeper app (Android/Java) with a zoom option, 100% or 200% - no variable zoom, no zoom gestures for now.
Can I create a view twice as big as the screen, in width and height, and move it around; or do I have to move all the buttons and the labels?
I would like to have a toolbar at the top, with the number of bombs left, that doesn't move. How do I get the size of the rest of the screen?
The only examples of pan/gesture I found are for images, and they depend on the size of the image, not the size of the screen. Also, they don't move buttons and labels.

You don't show any code of how you plan to draw the buttons, toolbars, labels etc so it's difficult to give an more detailed answer.
Probably most likely as a starter to produce what you want is to use a ConstraintLayout to position buttons, toolbars, labels etc in the right positions and making board area to match the other constraints. Also making sure this Layout is no larger than the screen (so not in any scrollable layout)
Now I would read how Android draws it's UI guide documentation.
From this you should be able to see that you will need to create a custom View or ViewGroup by extending one of these classes to handle drawing the board (the bit you want to zoom)
In that View/ViewGroup you would override the onMeasure method where parent ConstraintLayout should pass to your custom View/ViewGroup the size to what your view has to draw into so it fits on the screen (If setup correctly)
You can then use double those measurements in how you draw your view or pass to your ViewGroups children view(s).
This will mean you View/Viewgroup will be partly drawn off screen but your buttons would set a Matrix on the View/ViewGroup to set it to translate (move) in various directions you want and scale (zoom) the required amount be invalidating the View/ViewGroup (to get it to be redrawn with the new Matrix).
(You can also use various setTranslationX, setTranslationY, setScaleX and setScaleY) to indirectly change the View/ViewGroup's matrix if you not so familiar with Matrix maths)
